# Mousetrap - Adding Wrapping Specific Elements gives error a.attachEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, mousetrap

I am using a JS library - Mousetrap `v1.6.1` for keyboard shortcuts.

I have 2 forms on my HTML page, `billheaderfrm`and `billfooterfrm`. I am using below code to bind to `headerfrm`

```
  var headerfrm = $('#billheaderfrm');
  Mousetrap(headerfrm).bind('ctrl+s', function(e, combo) {
    e.preventDefault();
    headerfrm.submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      updatebillheader();
    });
    return false;
  });
```

I have added the above code in jquery `$(document).ready(function()` .

When the page loads, i get an error in console - `TypeError: a.attachEvent is not a function`

FYI: As per the documentation, binding to selected element is supported since version 1.5.

Comment: I thought jquery object and DOM element is same thing. So, I guess, I will need to change to `var headerfrm = document.getElementById("billheaderfrm");` am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#billheaderfrm')` is a jQuery object, and jQuery objects don't have `attachEvent` methods. Bind to a DOM element instead:

```
var headerfrm = document.getElementById('billheaderfrm');
Mousetrap(headerfrm).bind('ctrl+s', function(e, combo) { ...
```